# JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to persist user information(firstname and last name) using JPA, but varchar columns are not accepting characters of languages like Arabic, Malayalam , Telugu etc including emojies.

The table structure is as follows:

```
    @Entity
    public class UserTrueCallerInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

followed by getters and setters.

```
            UserTrueCallerInfo userTrueCallerInfo = new UserTrueCallerInfo();
            userTrueCallerInfo.setFirstName("ABC");
            userTrueCallerInfo.setLastName("അസാദ്");
            userTrueCallerInfoRepository.save(userTrueCallerInfo);
```

Doing so I am getting the below error,

```
> JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x90\x90\x90\xF0\x90...' for column 'lastName' at row 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x90\x90\x90\xF0\x90...' for column 'lastName' at row 

**NOTE** default character set is "UTF-8" and i tried using 4 byte "utf8mb4" as follows 

> ALTER TABLE UserTrueCallerInfo CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Still i am unable to persist the user details in the table. Please find below persistence.properties

```
    jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/epay?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_unicode_ci&characterSetResults=UTF-8
    jdbc.username=abc
    jdbc.password=abc**
    jdbc.driver.classname=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.show.sql=false
    jdbc.generate.ddl=true
    jdbc.database=MYSQL
    jdbc.database.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need to make sure your DB is the correct charset, it would also be useful to see your hibernate properties and see this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358475/utf-8-from-hibernate) answer for setting hibernate properties.

Comment: @zmf  Here is my hibernate properties url      [link] (jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/epay?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_unicode_ci&characterSetResults=UTF-8)